# Where are SVG launcher icons automatically loaded from?

Tags: icons, .desktop

I have created several desktop shortcuts for VirtualBox machines (VBMs) on my 15.04 Ubuntu OS. I've noticed that desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications` usually have single word values for the `Icon` key (i.e., the line that goes `Icon=...`) in them and I was wondering if the same thing might be possible for these VBM desktop files. See I have several SVG versions of the VBM's logos (like one for Arch Linux, another for Debian, another for Fedora and so on) that I downloaded from Wikimedia Commons and Wikipedia, that I'd like to use in these desktop configuration files, but instead of long complicated file locations for these logos I was wondering if I might also use a single word name for them like that used in the desktop entries in `/usr/share/applications` & `~/.local/share/applications`.

For example, I'd like:

```
Icon=Arch
```

to point to a logo called `Arch.svg`, for instance. Where do I have to put this SVG in order for this to be possible? By the way I'd like these icons to be icon theme-independent, i.e., if I were to change my current icon theme from Faenza to Humanity, I'd like these icons to remain unchanged.

[image]

Comment: `/usr/share/icons/*/scalable` for system-wide, `~/.local/share/icons/*/scalable` for your user. The `*` depends on the theme.

Comment: Don't you mean `/usr/share/icons/*/apps/scalable`?

Comment: Pretty sure if the `apps` folder exists, it would exist within `scalable` and not the other way around.